# Cancel Pending intent/ Alarm after triggered

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I create a notification with the following code, but after the notification is triggered, when I check if the alarm, it is still on. Shouldn't it be disabled from the system once it is fired? How can I handle this?

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NotifyCallService.class);
myIntent.putExtra("lastName", lastName);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 11, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, pendingIntent);
```

I check the alarm with the following code:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), NotifyCallService.class);
boolean alarmUp = (PendingIntent.getService(getActivity(), 11, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pendingIntent` is still there, but not necessarily your alarm. If you want to ensure the alarm is inactive, call `alarmManager.cancel()`.